# how to use two application name tags in android manifest

Tags: android

I am using  `AppController` in my LoginActivity and my app minimum SDK version is 15, so in my manifest I mentioned.

```
android:name=".AppController"
```

and

```
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

but its allowing to use one name tag in `<application>`

how to solve this issue?

Comment: You want 2 name tags under application tag? @Asesha

Comment: Make your AppController extend MultiDexApplication and use android:name=".AppController" in your manifest

Comment: ya other wise my app is not working in SDK 15

Comment: You can have only one tag, try solution suggested by @aroniez

Comment: Ya you have to implement it using Inheritance concept, as Aroniez mentioned above. @AseshaGeorge

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Comment: do i need to extend MultiDexApplication in all Activities or only in Launch Activity

Comment: only to your application class

Comment: i mean create .AppController which extends Applicaton and give it in android:name=".AppController" in manifest with below answer

Comment: You got it @AseshaGeorge ?

Comment: Check this out: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-gradle

Comment: guys did you see somebody down vote  my question. what's wrong in my question i hate down voting i feel like insult.

Comment: It's superb question @AseshaGeorge. Is not question like need to downvote. i'll vote up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you can try this it work in my case 
add your multidex. code in your AppController class
 like this

```
public class AppController extends Application 
{ 

  // your code of AppController
...

  // add here your multidex code like this
   @Override
   protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
   }

}
```

Comment: It is only need in your application class which extends Application @AseshaGeorge

Comment: you don't need to add in all activity just add in App controller

Comment: @AseshaGeorge check it

Comment: @AseshaGeorge most Welcome enjoy coding

Answer (score 0):

> but its allowing to use one name tag in

You cannot have more than one `android:name` attribute in application tag.

From the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html):

You have two ways:

If you do override the Application class, change it to extend MultiDexApplication (if possible) as follows:

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication { ... }
```

Or if you do override the Application class but it's not possible to change the base class, then you can instead override the attachBaseContext() method and call MultiDex.install(this) to enable multidex:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
  @Override
  protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
     super.attachBaseContext(base);
     MultiDex.install(this);
  }
}
```